# Stack Overflow is planning to give their non-programming Machine Learning questions wholesale to Cross Validated

Tags: discussion, migration, cross-validated, stack-overflow

Just a note that Stack Overflow is looking to give away their closed questions on theoretical (i.e. non-programming) aspects of ML to Cross Validated:

- [Let's gift wrap our (good) Machine Learning theory questions for Cross Validated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404799/lets-gift-wrap-our-good-machine-learning-theory-questions-for-cross-validated) (SO Meta)
- [Would Cross Validated want Machine Learning Theory questions that are no longer on-topic for Stack Overflow?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6066/would-cross-validated-want-machine-learning-theory-questions-that-are-no-longer) (CV Meta)

I guess that Data Science SE may be also interested in hosting some of these questions, hence this post here.

I was not at all involved (in fact I have argued in SO Meta that we should keep them there, but I am clearly with the minority), but to the best of my knowledge, no other relevant SE site (namely AI and Data Science) has been asked if they would possibly be interested to receive some of them, too.

Comment: Thank you. I saw that post on SO Meta.  I upvoted your answer.  However I agree with your analysis that you are in the minority opinion, and think that advocating for bringing them here is likely an even steeper uphill battle than leaving them in place.

Comment: I don't think it would hurt to express an interest (and I did so, but a DS moderator would carry more weight).  But, I did look through the top-voted closed questions with tag machine-learning, and I do think most of those belong better at CV.  If they continue making a list, I'll check in now and again.